# Adding middleware after app.router

Tags: node.js, express

I have a server with the following defined :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // gets something
}

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  // updates something, need to be authenticated
}
```

Now I want the `post` action to be only for authenticated users, so I want to add a `auth` middleware between them like this :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // gets something
}

app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  // check for authentication
}

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  // updates something, need to be authenticated
}
```

This way, `GET` gets through and for `POST`, user has to be authenticated.

The problem is that express doesn't go in to my `app.use` middleware. If i put the `app.use` middleware before all of the `app.VERB` routes, it works.

Is there any way to do it like I want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare your first route, Express automatically inserts `app.router` into the middleware chain. Since the router gets to handle any following routes, any middleware that you declare after that first route will not get to handle your routes.

But instead of using `app.use`, you can use the fact that route-handlers are very similar to middleware:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // gets something
});

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) { // catches GET, POST, ... to '/'
  // check for authentication
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  // updates something, need to be authenticated
});
```

But if you only have a single route that needs to be passed through the middleware, it makes sense to follow the advise of @hiattp and add the middleware to the route declaration immediately.

Comment: I am wondering if something has changed since express 2.x because I am certain i've previously defined `app.use()` after `app.VERB()` and it was working okay

Comment: @Michael tested with `express@2.5.1`, seems to have the same behaviour as 3.x ([gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/bf45da5dc0a5947b237f))

Comment: You can also use app.all('*')

Answer (score 2):

I like to put this type of check in a reuseable method and pass it into the route handler:

```
function ensureAuth(req, res, next){
  if(req.user) next(); // Auth check
  else res.redirect('/');
}

app.post('/', ensureAuth, function(req,res){
  // User is authenticated
}
```

Comment: This is nice, although I will have to put it in each route I define later which is kind of a bummer if you have lots of routes